# Replace middle part of a string with something else using a SQL query

Tags: sql, wordpress, string, replace

I am moving from a file sharing website to a dedicated server.
I transferred all my 4500 links to the server.
As previous links were from that file sharing website, they have a somehow complex format.
I want to replace my old links which have random characters in middle of their URLs, with the new ones that are cleanly formatted, in all wordpress tables.
Tried many queries even with % and _ wildcards, got no result at all.
Searched this website and other sites as well, all were about changing first number of characters of a string or replacing a complete String with a new one.

No one had this problem that I’m currently facing.
Example:
One of my old links is:
http://luckymojy.dl1.rapidpars.com/21520/11166830/bj83fhh0v8h/Crowd%2520Laughing%2520Sound%2520Effects.mp4
That should be replaced with the following:
http://gooshkon.ir/dl/Crowd%2520Laughing%2520Sound%2520Effects.mp4
Or look at this one
Old link:
luckymojy.dl4.rapidpars.com/21520/7457627/c96r7emjghm/Juliet%2520%26%2520ET%2520Series%2520Braille%2520Embossers.flv
New link:
gooshkon.ir/dl/Juliet%2520%26%2520ET%2520Series%2520Braille%2520Embossers.flv
Note that these old links from file sharing website have a pattern:
user_name.download_server.rapidpars.com/account_no/file_no/file_serial/file_name.ext
That should be modified as follows:
gooshkon.ir/dl/file_name.ext
The file_nos are 6 digits, 7 digits and some of them are 8 digits.
All other parameters have a constant length.
Is it possible to modify all the links at once?
The string before file names should be replaced with gooshkon.ir/dl/
Actually, the file names should remain intact.
Changing 4500 links manually is a tedious task.
Any solution to this one?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are here to help you in **your code**. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read through the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out how to ask a question that is acceptable in the forum.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the REPLACE command. You can do something like this (I create a temporary table just to example).

```
    CREATE TABLE #LINKS
    (
        MY_LINK VARCHAR(255)
    )

    INSERT INTO #LINKS VALUES ('http://luckymojy.dl1.rapidpars.com/21520/11166830/bj83fhh0v8h/Crowd%2520Laughing%2520Sound%2520Effects.mp4')
    INSERT INTO #LINKS VALUES ('luckymojy.dl4.rapidpars.com/21520/7457627/c96r7emjghm/Juliet%2520%26%2520ET%2520Series%2520Braille%2520Embossers.flv')


    DECLARE @TEXT_TO_REMOVE VARCHAR(255) = 'http://luckymojy.dl1.rapidpars.com/21520/11166830/bj83fhh0v8h/'
    DECLARE @TEXT_TO_SUBSTITUTE VARCHAR(255) = 'http://gooshkon.ir/dl/'

    UPDATE      #LINKS
    SET         MY_LINK =REPLACE(MY_LINK,@TEXT_TO_REMOVE,@TEXT_TO_SUBSTITUTE)
    WHERE       MY_LINK LIKE @TEXT_TO_REMOVE + '%'



    SET @TEXT_TO_REMOVE = 'luckymojy.dl4.rapidpars.com/21520/7457627/c96r7emjghm/'
    SET @TEXT_TO_SUBSTITUTE = 'gooshkon.ir/dl/'


    UPDATE      #LINKS
    SET         MY_LINK =REPLACE(MY_LINK,@TEXT_TO_REMOVE,@TEXT_TO_SUBSTITUTE)
    WHERE       MY_LINK LIKE @TEXT_TO_REMOVE + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filename is:

```
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(MYLINK, '/', -1)
```

To prepend it with the new path:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('path/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_path, '/', -1))
FROM
  wordpress_move
```

Example fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/196e8c/2/0